# how to properly instantiate an array of pointers in constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, instantiation

Simple question about instantiating an array through a constructor.
I have an array of pointers to class x, I'm trying to set the array members to nullptr through the constructor.

This is my y.h

```
#include <array>
#include "x.h"

class y
{
public:

static const size_t number = 20;
y();


private:
std::array<x*, number> arrayList;
};
```

this is my y.cpp

```
#include "y.h"
#include "x.h"
#include <array>

using namespace std;

y::y()
: arrayList(nullptr)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use value initialization:

```
y::y()
: arrayList()
{
}
```

or

```
y::y()
: arrayList{}
{
}
```